# jQuery CSS3 Question

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if anybody knew of a good way of changing some css3 using jQuery.

I figured I would use something like a selector:

```
$("#con_back").css('-webkit-border-top-right-radius','0px');
$("#con_back").css('border-top-right-radius','0px');
$("#con_back").css('-moz-border-radius-topright','0px');
```

But I just can't work it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do? what have you tried? is there some real code which doesn't work?

Comment: What is the real problem ??
What Error Occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("#con_back").addClass('css3');

    **CSS**

    .css3 {
           -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
           -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
           -moz-border-radius-topright:0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

I think your problem was you were not setting any # (using 0 only for the radius).  With a zero radius, you get a straight edge.

Try this.

```
$("#con_back").css('-webkit-border-top-right-radius','10px');
$("#con_back").css('border-top-right-radius','10px');
$("#con_back").css('-moz-border-radius-topright','10px');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/eraTw/